# Problema estableciendo colorscheme en vim

Tags: vim, colorscheme

Quería instalar deep-space

Hice todo el proceso:

Plug 'tyrannicaltoucan/vim-deep-space'

:w

:source ~/.vimrc

:PlugInstall

Aparentemente se instaló correctamente ya que decía "finishing...done", de hecho el archivo .vimrc inmediatamente cambió al color deep-space, pero lo cerré y cuando quise abrir el archivo en el que estoy trabajando me sale "E185 Cannot find color scheme 'deep-space'".

Después de abrir el archivo, en el menú de colores sí aparece deep-space y lo puedo utilizar (lo que indica que sí está instalado, así que no entiendo por qué sale error) pero lo que quiero es que me quede como predeterminado.